# Need help debugging

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, range

The function I'm trying to produce is called:

```
int Range(int values[], int numValues)
```

The purpose is to  return the difference between the largest value in the array and the smallest value in the array.

Below is my code however it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Range(int values[], int numValues)
{
    int i;
    int large;
    int small;
    int displayone;
    int displaytwo;
    int calc;

    large = values[0];
    small = values[0];

    for(i=0;i<numValues;i++){

        if(values[i]>large){
            displayone = values[i];
        }
        else if(values[i] < small){
            displaytwo = values[i];
        }
    }

    calc = displayone - displaytwo;

    return calc;
}
```

Comment: Remove `displayone` and `displaytwo` from the code, and just use `large` and `small`.

Comment: @user3386109: Just telling a person what changes to make does not necessarily help them understand what is wrong. To a person just learning something completely new, things may seem like a great mystery. To help them, you ought to explain what the code they showed is doing that is different from what they might be expecting or wanting. If you can figure out what ideas they had that led to their mistakes, it can be helpful to correct them.

Comment: Hey my code compiles now. I have one last question....I understand what the function is asking me to do(find range i.e. largest value - smallest value) but could you please explain why you suggested to replace displayone and displaytwo with large and small?

Comment: Hi Shiv, welcome to Stack Overflow! Always try to include the error or problem you're having in the question; simply saying "it doesn't work" can increase the time it takes for you to get an answer.

Comment: Ok Matt, will do with future questions. Thanks for letting me know :)....Like I said this is by far the best coding forum website I've used!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the small and large values correctly.  You can remove the `displayone` and `displaytwo` variables as they're not needed.  Just use `large` and `small` to track the values in the loop.

Strictly speaking, to make the function robust, you should also consider a couple of other things:

1. *The case where the number of elements is zero (or less)* -  In this case the range would be undefined.  Returning zero is probably the best we can do.
2. *That the result of the subtraction of one `int` value from another can lead to an overflow* - For example, consider INT_MAX - INT_MIN.  The result of this, about 4 billion, is a lot more than the roughly 2 billion an unsigned `int` can represent.  Mathematically, the range will always be a positive number; a negative one probably doesn't make sense here.  So making the return type `unsigned int` should be appropriate and prevent overflows, along with ensuring the intermediate `large` and `small` variables are expanded to `long long` to allow the final subtraction to happen correctly.

With all of the considerations above, the function becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int Range(int values[] , int numValues)
{
    int i;
    long long large;               // <<<< Make long long to support ...
    long long small;               // <<<< ... final subtraction
    unsigned int calc;             // <<<< Make unsigned int to match return

    if (numValues < 1)             // <<<< Handle invalid input
        return 0;

    large = values[0];
    small = values[0];

    for(i=0;i<numValues;i++){

        if(values[i]>large)  
            large = values[i];      // <<<< assign to large here
        else if(values[i] < small)
            small = values[i];      // <<<< and similar for small
    }

    calc = (uint)(large - small);           // <<<< then calculate difference

    return calc;    
}
```

Comment: Always thank on StackOverflow by upvoting!  You're welcome ;)

Comment: Note that if there are no values in the array, you attempt to compute `INT_MIN - INT_MAX` which incurs signed arithmetic overflow and therefore undefined behaviour.  You may need to trap zero values as a special case; the range is probably best represented as zero too.  Then the original code using `large = small = values[0];` is a reasonable start.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, yes I've been thinking about that too, along with other things that should be considered in this function.  Answer updated.

Comment: `#include <stdexcept>` and `throw std::invalid_argument("numValues cannot be less than 1");` aren't particularly C-like; they won't compile with a pure C compiler. You can't even macro-process the `::` out of existence and that's a syntax error in C. I think I'd use `return 0;` instead of throwing an exception (and I'd simply omit the extra include). The extra steps you've taken work for the normal situation where the value type is `int` and `sizeof(long long) > sizeof(int)`. It's faintly interesting (to sufficiently devious minds) to work out what's necessary if the value type is `long long`.

Comment: If the value type is an unsigned type (`unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`), then the code is straight-forward and obvious. There's neither overflow nor wraparound to worry about. Unless the minimum value is `INT_MIN` (or `LONG_MIN` or `LLONG_MIN`), then it is possible but circuitous to produce an answer w/o overflow by careful casting and addition instead of subtraction when the large and small values are of different signs. I haven't worked out how to handle `LLONG_MIN` when the value type is `signed long long` and there's no bigger type (but I'm sure it can be done).

Comment: Thanks again @JonathanLeffler for the extra comments, and alerting me to the fact that it's not C++!  Edited again to remove exception-throwing and just return zero in the case of invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4078718/ian)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563945/15168), if the numbers in the array can be both positive and negative and are only constrained by the limits on the type `int` and not some smaller range, you need to return the range as an unsigned integer because the largest integer minus the smallest integer overflows the range of valid integers (but the range of unsigned integers).

One way around the calculation problem is to use a longer signed type than the type of the array (which is what Ian's answer does), but that eventually runs into problems when there is no longer signed type.  The following code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `array-range-17.c` in the [src/so-5256-3870](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-5256-3870) sub-directory.  It uses only `int` and `unsigned` types without using any longer type.

```
/* SO 5256-3870 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static unsigned ArrayRange(size_t num_values, int values[num_values])
{
    int large;
    int small;
    unsigned range;

    if (num_values < 1)
        return 0;

    large = values[0];
    small = values[0];

    for (size_t i = 1; i < num_values; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] > large)
            large = values[i];
        else if (values[i] < small)
            small = values[i];
    }

    if ((large >= 0 && small >= 0) || (large <= 0 && small <= 0))
    {
        /* Most common cases - both values of same sign; no overflow risk */
        /* Any mode of binary arithmetic */
        assert(large >= small);
        range = large - small;
    }
    else if ((-INT_MAX == INT_MIN) || (small != INT_MIN))
    {
        /*
        ** Two's complement arithmetic with values with different signs
        ** but the small value is not INT_MIN, or one's complement
        ** arithmetic or sign-magnitude arithmetic (which have negative
        ** zeros but no asymmetry in the positive vs negative ranges).
        */
        /* Different signs — therefore large is positive and small is negative */
        assert(large > 0 && small < 0);
        range = (unsigned)large + (unsigned)(-small);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Twos-complement arithmetic — small is INT_MIN */
        assert(-INT_MAX - 1 == INT_MIN);
        assert(small == INT_MIN && large > 0);
        range = (unsigned)large + INT_MAX + 1;
    }

    return range;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arrays[][2] =
    {
        { +345, +436 },
        { +436, +345 },
        { -199, -439 },
        { -439, -199 },
        { -999, +999 },
        { +999, -999 },
        { 0, 0 },
        { 0, INT_MAX },
        { 0, INT_MIN },
        { 0, INT_MAX },
        { -1000, INT_MAX },
        { +1000, INT_MAX },
        { -1000, INT_MIN },
        { +1000, INT_MIN },
        { INT_MIN, INT_MAX },
        { INT_MIN, INT_MIN },
        { INT_MAX, INT_MAX },
        { INT_MIN, -INT_MAX },
    };
    enum { NUM_ARRAYS = sizeof(arrays) / sizeof(arrays[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAYS; i++)
    {
        unsigned int range = ArrayRange(2, arrays[i]);
        printf("%+11d:%+-11d = %u\n", arrays[i][0], arrays[i][1], range);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The testing code only plays with arrays with two elements, but it works with bigger arrays too.  The output is:

```
       +345:+436        = 91
       +436:+345        = 91
       -199:-439        = 240
       -439:-199        = 240
       -999:+999        = 1998
       +999:-999        = 1998
         +0:+0          = 0
         +0:+2147483647 = 2147483647
         +0:-2147483648 = 2147483648
         +0:+2147483647 = 2147483647
      -1000:+2147483647 = 2147484647
      +1000:+2147483647 = 2147482647
      -1000:-2147483648 = 2147482648
      +1000:-2147483648 = 2147484648
-2147483648:+2147483647 = 4294967295
-2147483648:-2147483648 = 0
+2147483647:+2147483647 = 0
-2147483648:-2147483647 = 1
```

As I noted in comments, if the integer type of the array is unsigned, the code is very simple; there are no overflows to worry about, and the data all has the same sign of necessity.

You can parameterize the code above to work with different integer types.  Here is some code that can compiled with:

- `-DUSE_INTMAX` - use `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`.
- `-DUSE_LONG_LONG` — use `long long` and `unsigned long long`.
- `-DUSE_LONG` — use `long` and `unsigned long`.
- `-DUSE_INT64` — use `int64_t` and `uint64_t`.
- `-DUSE_INT32` — use `int32_t` and `uint32_t`.
- `-DUSE_INT16` — use `int16_t` and `uint16_t`.
- `-DUSE_INT` (or none of the above) — use `int` and `unsigned`.

Adding `short`, `signed char`, and `int8_t` is left as a not very exciting exercise for the reader.

```
/* SO 5256-3870 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* Paramterization for signed types */
#if defined(USE_INTMAX)
typedef intmax_t SignedType;
typedef uintmax_t UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  INTMAX_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  INTMAX_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "20" PRIdMAX
#define RANGE_FMT   PRIuMAX
#elif defined(USE_LONG_LONG)
typedef long long SignedType;
typedef unsigned long long UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  LLONG_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  LLONG_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "20lld"
#define RANGE_FMT   "llu"
#elif defined(USE_LONG)
typedef long SignedType;
typedef unsigned long UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  LONG_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  LONG_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "20ld"      // 11ld would do is sizeof(long) == 4
#define RANGE_FMT   "lu"
#elif defined(USE_INT64)
typedef int64_t SignedType;
typedef uint64_t UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  INT64_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  INT64_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "20" PRId64
#define RANGE_FMT   PRIu64
#elif defined(USE_INT32)
typedef int32_t SignedType;
typedef uint32_t UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  INT32_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  INT32_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "11" PRId32
#define RANGE_FMT   PRIu32
#elif defined(USE_INT16)
typedef int16_t SignedType;
typedef uint16_t UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  INT16_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  INT16_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "6" PRId16
#define RANGE_FMT   PRIu16
#else /* USE_INT */
typedef int SignedType;
typedef unsigned UnsignedType;
#define SIGNED_MAX  INT_MAX
#define SIGNED_MIN  INT_MIN
#define DATA_FMT    "11d"
#define RANGE_FMT   "u"
#endif

static UnsignedType ArrayRange(size_t num_values, SignedType values[num_values])
{
    if (num_values == 0)
        return 0;

    SignedType large = values[0];
    SignedType small = values[0];

    for (size_t i = 1; i < num_values; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] > large)
            large = values[i];
        else if (values[i] < small)
            small = values[i];
    }

    UnsignedType range;
    assert(small <= large);
    if (small >= 0 || large < 0 || (large == 0 && small != SIGNED_MIN))
    {
        /* Most common cases - both values of same sign; no overflow risk */
        /* Any mode of binary arithmetic */
        assert(large >= small);
        range = large - small;
    }
    else if ((-SIGNED_MAX == SIGNED_MIN) || (small != SIGNED_MIN))
    {
        /*
        ** Two's complement arithmetic with values with different signs
        ** but the small value is not SIGNED_MIN, or one's complement
        ** arithmetic or sign-magnitude arithmetic (which have negative
        ** zeros but no asymmetry in the positive vs negative ranges).
        */
        /* Different signs — therefore large is positive and small is negative */
        assert(large > 0 && small < 0);
        range = (UnsignedType)large + (UnsignedType)(-small);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Twos-complement arithmetic — small is SIGNED_MIN */
        assert(-SIGNED_MAX - 1 == SIGNED_MIN);
        assert(small == SIGNED_MIN && large >= 0);
        range = (UnsignedType)large + SIGNED_MAX + 1;
    }

    return range;
}

int main(void)
{
    SignedType arrays[][2] =
    {
        { +345, +436 },
        { +436, +345 },
        { -199, -439 },
        { -439, -199 },
        { -999, +999 },
        { +999, -999 },
        { 0, 0 },
        { 0, SIGNED_MAX },
        { 0, SIGNED_MIN },
        { 0, SIGNED_MAX },
        { -1000, SIGNED_MAX },
        { +1000, SIGNED_MAX },
        { -1000, SIGNED_MIN },
        { +1000, SIGNED_MIN },
        { SIGNED_MIN, SIGNED_MAX },
        { SIGNED_MIN, SIGNED_MIN },
        { SIGNED_MAX, SIGNED_MAX },
        { SIGNED_MIN, -SIGNED_MAX },
    };
    enum { NUM_ARRAYS = sizeof(arrays) / sizeof(arrays[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAYS; i++)
    {
        UnsignedType range = ArrayRange(2, arrays[i]);
        printf("%+" DATA_FMT ":%+-" DATA_FMT " = %" RANGE_FMT "\n",
               arrays[i][0], arrays[i][1], range);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `-DUSE_INTMAX` on a Mac running macOS 10.14 Mojave, compiled with GCC 8.2.0, I get the result:

```
                +345:+436                 = 91
                +436:+345                 = 91
                -199:-439                 = 240
                -439:-199                 = 240
                -999:+999                 = 1998
                +999:-999                 = 1998
                  +0:+0                   = 0
                  +0:+9223372036854775807 = 9223372036854775807
                  +0:-9223372036854775808 = 9223372036854775808
                  +0:+9223372036854775807 = 9223372036854775807
               -1000:+9223372036854775807 = 9223372036854776807
               +1000:+9223372036854775807 = 9223372036854774807
               -1000:-9223372036854775808 = 9223372036854774808
               +1000:-9223372036854775808 = 9223372036854776808
-9223372036854775808:+9223372036854775807 = 18446744073709551615
-9223372036854775808:-9223372036854775808 = 0
+9223372036854775807:+9223372036854775807 = 0
-9223372036854775808:-9223372036854775807 = 1
```

I am confident the code works on a machine that uses two's complement arithmetic.  I believe it would work on a machine that uses one's complement or sign-magnitude arithmetic, but I'm not able to test that.